# How can I reference a parent resource field in a child resource in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I've got the following terraform config (somewhat incomplete since it doesn't show the relationship between resources):

```
resource "exchange" "foo" {
  display_name = "test-exchange-foo"
  // this resource has a compute property api_endpoint
}

resource "topic" "orders_1" {
  display_name = "orders-topic-1"
  // this resource needs to reference api_endpoint from cluster.foo

resource "topic" "orders_2" {
  display_name = "orders-topic-2"
  // this resource needs to reference api_endpoint from cluster.foo
}
```

`exchange` resource has 1-to-many relationship with `topic` resource and I want to create a single exchange and 2 topics assigned to it. The tricky part is I'm writing my customer tf provider for both `topic` and `exchange` and the topics client needs to know `exchange.foo.api_endpoint` in runtime to send a request to the right API server.

How can I pass `api_endpoint` to `topic.orders_1 / topic.orders_2`? Can I just write something like:

```
resource "exchange" "foo" {
  display_name = "test-exchange-foo"
  // this resource has a compute property api_endpoint
}

resource "topic" "orders_1" {
  display_name = "orders-topic-1"
  endpoint     = exchange.foo.api_endpoint // will it work?
  // this resource needs to reference api_endpoint from cluster.foo
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes: `endpoint = exchange.foo.api_endpoint`

Comment: @MarkB done! Is it the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's how you reference properties of other resources in Terraform.

Comment: What is `cluster.foo`? "will it work?" - just try and see what you get.